# Any way to use URL Fetch Service in .NET Core?

Tags: google-app-engine, asp.net-core, urlfetch

Just ran into an issue where I have a service in Google App Engine Flex (GAEF) attempting to perform a GET operation on another service in GAEF (within the same Project) only to get a 403. After hours of guessing, I just added the caller's VM IP Address in the firewall rule to Allow and everything worked. I later read that URL Fetch service uses a set pool of static ip addresses which I could use reliably instead of having to constantly update the firewall rules whenever the caller has a new ip address.

Unfortunately, I don't see anywhere on how I can use this on .net core. Anybody run into this before?

Comment: you should use shared VPC to allow your flexible app engine service to talk to each other  and apply your firewall rule there

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/using-shared-vpc

Comment: Seems like overkill for such a simple ask. I'm guessing it's not possible otherwise?

Comment: you may feel it is overkill, but remember your code is running in a public cloud, where many people are running their code on physical hardware ( you are using virtual hardware)  hence your code has to follow strict Software-defined isolation  pattern

Comment: Unfortunately, the libraries for URLFetch service are available only for Python 2.7 , Java 8 and PHP5.